# The shower water suddenly gets hotter, suddenly goes from 105 to 111F

Tags: plumbing, shower

This is not caused by a pressure drop as far as I can tell, flushing the toilet doesn't affect it and it happens with no other water usage. it can happen 10-15 minutes into a shower, not just at the start. I've replaced the cartridge and the shower head. The water heater and pressure valve coming into the house are new, the problem seemed to appear some months after they were installed.

I'm looking for any and all suggestions I even bought a shower head with a thermometer to track it.

Comment: This sometimes is caused by a failure in a thermostatic shower valve or one with an anti-scald component. What type, brand and model valve is in your shower?  Most homes also have anti-scald mixing valves at the water heater. When they start to  fail they can be unreliable.

Comment: 10 to 15 minutes of use sounds like water heater is turning on again and you are getting the hotter water from heater/s.

Comment: Is it a standard water heater (electric or gas), a tankless system or indirect fired water heater?

Comment: I believe it uses a delta RP19804 cartridge. It's been replaced twice now. It's a gas water heater. The 10-15 minutes  varies widely, it can also happen more than one during a shower, so I don't think it's the water heater starting up.

Comment: Are you on a well? A pressure change from the pump kicking in can mess with thermostatically controlled valves.

Comment: I'm not on a well. I'm getting a pressure guage to rule out fluctuations in pressure.

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured it out, the problem was different from what I thought. The real problem is that 3 of the 4 RP19804 I tried were defective. You could not adjust the temperature in small increments, any small change caused wild temperature swings. Putting a handle instead of a knobs helped a little, but the real answer was to keep trying valves until I found one that worked.

Comment: That's frustrating....